# setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build. Error after refactoring AKA putting GestureDetector inside a container

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm following this tutorial in creating these two containers in a row where, when clicked, the color changes.

It had worked using a longer, dirtier version of the code.

```
enum GenderType { male, female }

class InputPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _InputPageState createState() => _InputPageState();
}

class _InputPageState extends State<InputPage> {
  GenderType? selectedGender;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI CALCULATOR'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = GenderType.male;
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableContainer(
                      colour: selectedGender == GenderType.male
                          ? activeCardColor
                          : inactiveContainerColor,
                      containerChild:
                          ContainerChildColumn(FontAwesomeIcons.male, "Male"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    onTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = GenderType.female;
                      });
                    },
                    child: ReusableContainer(
                      colour: selectedGender == GenderType.female
                          ? activeCardColor
                          : inactiveContainerColor,
                      containerChild: ContainerChildColumn(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.female, "Female"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
```

Reusable Container

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ReusableContainer extends StatelessWidget {
      ReusableContainer({@required this.colour, this.containerChild});
    
      final Color? colour;
      final Widget? containerChild;
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: containerChild,
          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            color: colour,
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

However, in this tutorial, we were asked to "refactor" and make the code cleaner. So I followed it by transferring the GestureDetector Widget to the ReusableContainer class.

```
class ReusableContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  ReusableContainer(
      {@required this.colour, this.containerChild, this.ownOnTap});

  final Color? colour;
  final Widget? containerChild;
  final Function? ownOnTap;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: ownOnTap?.call(),
      child: Container(
        child: containerChild,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          color: colour,
```

and

```
Expanded(
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableContainer(
                    ownOnTap: () {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedGender = GenderType.male;
                      });
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == GenderType.male
                        ? activeCardColor
                        : inactiveContainerColor,
                    containerChild:
                        ContainerChildColumn(FontAwesomeIcons.male, "Male"),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ReusableContainer(
                    ownOnTap: () {
                      selectedGender = GenderType.female;
                    },
                    colour: selectedGender == GenderType.female
                        ? activeCardColor
                        : inactiveContainerColor,
                    containerChild:
                        ContainerChildColumn(FontAwesomeIcons.female, "Female")
```

I followed the tutorial line-by-line and it's supposed to work. However, it does not work on my side and instead shows this error

[image]

I tried removing the SetStates on both widgets and the error disappears BUT it's useless because the code wouldn't update and the colors don't change when pressed.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the function directly by doing `onTap: ownOnTap?.call(),`. Instead, you must try something like

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: () {
     ownOnTap?.call();
    }
    // your code
)
```

Or more simply

```
GestureDetector(
    onTap: ownOnTap
    // your code
)
```

Comment: My problem is why does it crash when I add setState inside the refactored ownOnTap?

Comment: The problem is not actually `setState`, it's calling "calling a function when building a widget". You widgets must be shown before you try to call function function by handling an event on them

Comment: Your first recommendation worked! Thank you sooooo much. I appreciate ittttt <3